# Moving VM from hard drive to SSD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, virtual-machine, vmware

A hard drive was replaced with a much faster SSD. The contents of the hard drive, including a Windows 7 VM for VMware Workstation were copied over. Is there anything that must be done so the VM and guest OS can experience the improved hardware?

VMware's [article on SSD](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/14.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-3FBBB031-D8BA-4D02-99C2-282F806F47E8.html) states

> On Windows 7 virtual machines, only IDE and SATA virtual disks can
>   report their virtual disks as SSD. SCSI virtual disks only report as
>   SSD when used as a system drive in a virtual machine, or as a
>   mechanical drive when used as a data drive inside a virtual machine.

My VM is running Windows 7 and it's SCSI. So what do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a machine with a large fast SSD drive, copied my VMware folders to it (including VMX (preferences file) and left the VM as SCSI for the VM drive and it works fine and very fast on the SSD drive. So just use the VM as you have it. No issues.